# kinit from Python script using keytab

Tags: python, subprocess, kerberos, popen

Does anyone know how to kinit from within a python script using keytab; that is to avoid having to prompt for a password?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer use libraries such as `krbcontext`:

```
from krbcontext.context import krbContext

with krbContext(using_keytab=True, principal='[username]@[REALM]', keytab_file='/etc/security/keytabs/[name].keytab', ccache_file='/tmp/krb5cc_pid_appname'):
    pass
```

Comment: krbcontext wraps gssapi perfectly, I never could figure out how to use gssapi to authenticate a keytab. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

kinit_args - [ '/usr/bin/kinit', '-kt', '/home/username/username.keytab', 'username@realm' ]
subp = Popen(kinit_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
subp.wait()
```